# Are there any sources dealing with Clark's *Without Evidence or Argument: A Defense of Reformed Epistemology*?

Tags: reference-request, belief

Clark's argument seems to be in response to Clifford's *Ethics of Belief*. Are there any sources which attempt to defend Clifford's argument against Clark's supposed rebuttal?

Thank you very much, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper is discussed passim in Michael Sudduth, 'Reformed Epistemology and Christian Apologetics', Religious Studies, Vol. 39, No. 3 (Sep., 2003), pp. 299-321. See also Stanley N. Gundry, ed., Five Views on Apologetics, Zondervan, 2000, to which Clark contributes and in which his views are discussed and criticised : ISBN 10: 0310224764 / ISBN 13: 9780310224761.